# Export to Excel on Angular 4

Tags: excel, angular

I have a data table that is dynamically populated using Angular 4. I would like to export the table to excel. How can I achieve this in Angular 4. 
I'm looking for .xls and not .csv.

PS: I don't want to use Jquery libraries.

My app-component looks like this,

```
    <table id ="dataTable" class = "table table-hover">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Mode</th>
          <th>Distance</th>
          <th>Fare</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let date of dateList;let i = index">
          <td>{{date}}</td> 
          <td>{{address}}</td>
          <td>{{mode}}</td>
          <td>{{distance}}</td>
          <td>{{fare}}</td>
          <td>
             <a>Delete</a>
          </td>   
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think only Microsoft can create excel files. That's why you're paying it. You should create CSV files.

Comment: You can make a program that generate Excel file.Then, in the server you pass the data and create the Excel, after you download the file.

Comment: Although using xlsx might work, it is a huge library (1.3MB unzipped). Currently looking for alternatives, or might indeed make an API endpoint.

Answer (score 11):

For those who are still looking for a working answer.

```js
public export() {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.myDataModels);
    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, worksheet, 'Sheet1');
    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.createFileName());
}
```

This will save as an  xlsx file automatically
Got this from https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/tree/19620da30be2a7d7b9801938a0b9b1fd3c4c4b00/demos/angular2

Comment: Is the packages competent even for more advanced stuff as formatting (colors/boldness/font size etc.)? How about formulas so that the produced document has e.g. dynamic summations (the stuff that one creates in Excel by entering "*=$g5+$f5*")?

Comment: Avoid this library, it has a massive size of 1.3MB ungzipped as commented to the author's question.

Answer (score 10):

You can use XLSX for export to excel.

It will support json or array into excel.

Sample code

```js
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
  const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
  const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
  const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
  this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
}
```

For Save

```js
private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
  const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
    type: EXCEL_TYPE
  });
  const today = new Date();
  const date = today.getFullYear() + '' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '' + today.getDate() + '_';
  const time = today.getHours() + "-" + today.getMinutes() + "-" + today.getSeconds();
  const name = fileName + date + time;
  FileSaver.saveAs(data, name + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}
```

Reference for Angular 2+

[Xlsx for angular 2+](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/tree/19620da30be2a7d7b9801938a0b9b1fd3c4c4b00/demos/angular2)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I'm getting a compilation error with EXCEL_TYPE and FileSaver.
Cannot find EXCEL_TYPE

I have insalled the filesaver as well

Comment: use EXCEL_TYPE as the following                                                                   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8" and EXCEL_EXTENSION as ".xlsx"

Comment: const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' }); replace

Comment: Hi @shajan, heaps of thanks for the answer. But question, how do save a json data to excel with headers?

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul you can also add headers within json file.                                                 const data: any[] = [{'name': 'A', 'no': 1}, {'name': 'B', 'no': 2}];                                      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'SheetJS.xlsx');                                                                
Here name and no are headers.

Comment: @shajan, thank you. yes, I manage to create headers and I now know the technique.

Comment: @shajan thanks for the answer, one more issue in Ubuntu, window 7 work is fine but Ubuntu inside not working, getting this error file open time "due to an unexpected error libreoffice crashed."

Comment: @Chaudhary I believe the issue is on LibreOffice. Can you try with some other pdf viewers?

Comment: how to display image in excel file when we are using export to excel in angular ?

Comment: Avoid this library, it has a massive size of 1.3MB ungzipped as commented to the author's question.

Comment: but how do U do if you have a pagination control?? how you can save all rows??

Comment: @JavierAndresCaicedo you can directly use the array or JSON file if you are using client-side pagination because you have all the rows. For server-side pagination, you have to call an API to get all the rows and you can use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `xlsx` library to write and save excel file at the same time using `XLSX.writeFile()`

```
exportExcel(data: any[]){
   const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
   const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
   XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'my_file.xls', { bookType: 'xls', type: 'buffer' });
}
```

Comment: Avoid this library, it has a massive size of 1.3MB ungzipped as commented to the author's question.

Answer (score 1):

before install libary

```
npm i file-saver
npm i xlsx
```

Create service excel with name class ExcelService
ng g s excel/ExcelService
you can coppy below code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExcelServiceService {
  constructor() { }
  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {

    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    console.log('worksheet',worksheet);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }
  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
}
```

Create folder model in have class CountryInfo

```
export class CountryInfo {
    country: string;
    hydro: number;
    oil: number;
    gas: number;
    coal: number;
    nuclear: number;
}
```

you can clone example export a file excel in angular at **[github](https://github.com/tienanhcntt2/ExportExcelAngular)**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Although using xlsx might work, it is a huge library (1.3MB unzipped). Currently looking for alternatives, or might indeed make an API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that microsoft provide a Javascript plugin, usable with Angular, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2)