# How can i export content to excel with specific formatting in angular5?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, export-to-excel

I have an html in my component which results seems like this:

```
Min : __________            Max : ____________
Avg : __________

// Here tabel starts just beneath these lines in the same component

Time   |  S-4
 11:00 |  32
 11:05 |  24
 11:10 |  25
```

I have tried json2csv and other packages but they only allow json to export to CSV.
How can i export this content to excel file using angular5 in the same format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to Excel on Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802074/export-to-excel-on-angular-4)

Comment: @Geek but i alsow want headers. how can i add headers in it?

Comment: you can add everything man